# Scroll jarring when using jQuery scrollTop

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I am using a very simple piece of code to animate a scroll to the top of my page. The code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div#top').hover(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop:0
        }, 2500);
    });
});
```

For some reason, once the scroll has occurred, if you try to scroll down again, the page jars for a few seconds before allowing you to scroll down. It seems to be worst when using FF though it's not much better in the other browsers.

Does anybody have any ideas on how I can get the jarring to stop?

Comment: As an aside, I'm not sure if there is still a problem with Opera animating the html and body separately, but here is a [fix for it](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/01/18/jquery-smooth-scroll-bugs.html)

Comment: @fudgey Very kind, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass only a single function to `hover`, it'll get executed upon mouse enter *and* mouse leave. So as soon as your mouse leaves the `div#top` element, another scroll animation starts, though you don't see it until you try to scroll down.

Bind to `mouseenter` instead.

Comment: Ah, schoolboy error. I tried `mouseenter` and that jarred too so I've gone for `mouseover`. Thanks.